# No entity found for query - Exception

Tags: java, ejb

I'm creating EJB project. For server I'm using Wildfly 8.2, for database I'm using XAMPP. I have EJB project, for session manager(interface and implementation), JPA project for entities from tables, dynamic web project for servlets and jsp pages. I have issue while I am trying to get some data from database. Exception:

```
23:50:20,901 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-3) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component BazenSessionManager for method public abstract model.Vlasnik sessions.BazenSessionManagerLocal.loginVlasnik(java.lang.String,java.lang.String): javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query
```

Caused by:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:498) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at sessions.BazenSessionManager.loginVlasnik(BazenSessionManager.java:40) [BazenEJB.jar:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.processInvocation(NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.java:59) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:273) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
... 62 more
```

Content under peristence tag:

```
    <persistence-unit name="BazenEAR">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/mysql</jta-data-source>
    <class>model.Izvestaj</class>
    <class>model.Neregularnost</class>
    <class>model.Plivac</class>
    <class>model.Poruka</class>
    <class>model.Skola</class>
    <class>model.Spasilac</class>
    <class>model.Termin</class>
    <class>model.Trener</class>
    <class>model.Vlasnik</class>    
</persistence-unit>
```

BazenEAR is name of EAR project where JPA project, EJB project and JPA project are included. model.Vlasnik.. is package.name of class which are automatically generated with option Generate entities from tables.
Vlasnik.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Vlasnik")
@NamedQuery(name="Vlasnik.findAll", query="SELECT v FROM Vlasnik v")
public class Vlasnik implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private int idvlasnika;

private String email;

private String ime;

private String lozinka;

private String prezime;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Izvestaj
@OneToMany(mappedBy="vlasnik")
private List<Izvestaj> izvestajs;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Neregularnost
@OneToMany(mappedBy="vlasnik")
private List<Neregularnost> neregularnosts;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Poruka
@OneToMany(mappedBy="vlasnik")
private List<Poruka> porukas;

public Vlasnik() {
}

public int getIdvlasnika() {
    return this.idvlasnika;
}

public void setIdvlasnika(int idvlasnika) {
    this.idvlasnika = idvlasnika;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return this.email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getIme() {
    return this.ime;
}

public void setIme(String ime) {
    this.ime = ime;
}

public String getLozinka() {
    return this.lozinka;
}

public void setLozinka(String lozinka) {
    this.lozinka = lozinka;
}

public String getPrezime() {
    return this.prezime;
}

public void setPrezime(String prezime) {
    this.prezime = prezime;
}

public List<Izvestaj> getIzvestajs() {
    return this.izvestajs;
}

public void setIzvestajs(List<Izvestaj> izvestajs) {
    this.izvestajs = izvestajs;
}

public Izvestaj addIzvestaj(Izvestaj izvestaj) {
    getIzvestajs().add(izvestaj);
    izvestaj.setVlasnik(this);

    return izvestaj;
}

public Izvestaj removeIzvestaj(Izvestaj izvestaj) {
    getIzvestajs().remove(izvestaj);
    izvestaj.setVlasnik(null);

    return izvestaj;
}

public List<Neregularnost> getNeregularnosts() {
    return this.neregularnosts;
}

public void setNeregularnosts(List<Neregularnost> neregularnosts) {
    this.neregularnosts = neregularnosts;
}

public Neregularnost addNeregularnost(Neregularnost neregularnost) {
    getNeregularnosts().add(neregularnost);
    neregularnost.setVlasnik(this);

    return neregularnost;
}

public Neregularnost removeNeregularnost(Neregularnost neregularnost) {
    getNeregularnosts().remove(neregularnost);
    neregularnost.setVlasnik(null);

    return neregularnost;
}

public List<Poruka> getPorukas() {
    return this.porukas;
}

public void setPorukas(List<Poruka> porukas) {
    this.porukas = porukas;
}

public Poruka addPoruka(Poruka poruka) {
    getPorukas().add(poruka);
    poruka.setVlasnik(this);

    return poruka;
}

public Poruka removePoruka(Poruka poruka) {
    getPorukas().remove(poruka);
    poruka.setVlasnik(null);

    return poruka;
}
```

loginVlasnik method from sessionmanager class:

```
    @Override
  public Vlasnik loginVlasnik(String email, String password) {
    Vlasnik vlasnik =(Vlasnik) entityManager.createQuery("select v from        Vlasnik v where v.email like :email").setParameter("email", email).getSingleResult();
    if (vlasnik != null && vlasnik.getLozinka().equals(password)) {
        return vlasnik;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Table vlasnik:

```
(IDVLASNIKA, IME, PREZIME, EMAIL, LOZINKA, primary key (IDVLASNIKA)
```

LoginVlasnik servlet (without import part):

```
@WebServlet("/LoginVlasnik")
public class LoginVlasnik extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@EJB
BazenSessionManagerLocal sessionManager;

public LoginVlasnik() {
    super();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String message = "";
    String page = "";
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    Vlasnik vlasnik = sessionManager.loginVlasnik(email, password);
    if (vlasnik != null) {
        message = "Uspesno ste prijavljeni";
        page = "vlasnik.jsp";
        request.setAttribute("message", message);
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(page);
        rd.forward(request, response);
    } else {
        message = "Morate se prvo registrovati.";
        page = "register.jsp";
        request.setAttribute("message", message);
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(page);
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

}

JSP page where I'm calling servlet:

```
<div>
<h3>Prijava vlasnika:</h3>
<form action="LoginVlasnik" method="post">
... fields for "email" and "lozinka"
</form
```

Do you have any idea what is happening here? Am I missing something? 
Deployment of EAR is successfull, I run the application, and when I click "Prijavi me" button, following error appears.